# DDR3 but 1.35v, little bit confused

Tags: memory, ddr3, cpu-z

CPU-z says that I have ddr3, but also it says that my ram is 1.35V I'm a little confused, how can ddr3 handle 1.35?. I'm planning to upgrade my ram,i have already chosen 2 sticks of 4GB PC3L 1.35V but first I want to make sure if I can upgrade it. it's weird when CPU z says [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6kz5.png)you have PC3 and 1.35v :D

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to find the manufacturer datasheet for your specific RAM, but a little research shows: it is already PC3L, so this might be a CPU-Z display bug.

Comment: I strongly recommend looking at the RAM HCL for your motherboard when selecting RAM.

Comment: Why exactly do you feel there is an issue with PC3L exactly?  It appears you already have 1.35V PC3L memory installed.  **I would only be concerned if your current memory was 1.5 (PC3) memory but it isn't.**

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the answer. I dont have issue with PC3L, my issue is that cpu z says i have DDR3 and as far as i know PC3L is DDR3L and not DDR3. so thats my only issue and i hope its CPU-Z bug. i want to order PC3L but im doing research first, i dont wanna burn my motherboard :D

Comment: Also guys, Do you know whats gonna happen if i just turn off my pc, and check motherboard/remove ram? to check which model exactly it is ?

Comment: @TeslaSolution - Your screenshot clearly shows your module is 1.35v which means it’s a PC3L module

Comment: Yup @Ramhound but why it doesnt show DDR3L :( i dont wanna burn my motherboard, it clearly says PC3-12800